# Java check if a position @array has a value or not

Tags: java, arrays, control-structure

hi i am sitting on a small library book exchange program in Java i want to understand programming a little more so my question is

i have this now

(buchRegal[0] == "" && buchregal_id[0] == null)

buchRegal[0] is a position from a String array and buchregal_id is part of a int Array.
With this code i learned i can check if a place at array[0] is empty, now  the problem i want it to check if there is something in it AND if so i want it to move to the next part of the array which should be array[0] and place it there until the end is reached

my english is bad by the way
greetings

Comment: in front of (buchRegal[0] == "" && buchregal_id == null) there is a IF

Comment: Please see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).